# Not able to generate Android signed apk

Tags: react-native

I am trying this from last 4 days and yet did not found any solution. I am using `react-native 0.61.5`. while running `./gradlew assembleRelease` I am getting:-

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * Where: Script '/Users/blickx/Desktop/dumont-reactnative/Dumont/node_modules/react-native/react.gradle'
>   line: 291
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'. react_cp2c21m954k2ml4rj79pw17zw$_run_closure4$_closure6$_closure10$_closure18
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create a new project from scratch and just copy all your files into new project. But first you can try if you are able to create apk in a new created project.

Comment: I am doing this project from last 1.5 year..!! Is there any better solution.?

Comment: You can try to run npm install in some cases it fixes errors connected with react.gradle

Comment: I did, but did not get any help. Getting same error.!

Comment: Try to make build in android studio not via terminal